# How get all parameters in express.js (post/get/etc.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, express

Is there a way to get in once all parameters sent using express.js? I know how do it to know the GET/POST separately, but is there a way to get everything at once?

I didn't found anything about that so far, it's useful to debug in particular.

Of course the `req.param(key)` works, but I want to have a list of all parameters, not have to retrieve them, just see them.

**Edit**: Add Route info:

```
consoleDev('Url: ' + req.method + ' ' + req.baseUrl + req._parsedUrl.href, 'debug');
consoleDev('Options: ' + JSON.stringify(options), 'debug');
consoleDev('Params: ' + Object.keys(req.params), 'debug');
consoleDev('Params: ' + (req.param('test')), 'debug');
```

Console:

```
debug: Url: GET http://localhost:5000/?test=5000
debug: Options: {"controllerName":"home","methodName":"index"}
debug: Params: 
debug: Params: 5000
```

Comment: change your route to `app.all('routename'...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot I created this topic few months ago and created another one where I got the answer to the question:

> You're looking for req.body, which contains the parsed POST body. (assuming you have middleware that parses it)
>
> See express.bodyParser()

[How log express.js POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703867/how-log-express-js-post-parameters/23703896?noredirect=1#23703896)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view the values passed you can just do

```
console.dir(req.params);
```

Or you can get the list of keys by using something like this:

```
keys = Object.keys(req.params);
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: `req.param` is a function. `req.params` is an array, but always empty when I send GET/POST params.

Comment: My bad. I've just edited my answer to reflect req.params as I originally intended. If the values are empty on POST you might be missing app.use(express.bodyParser()); in your code. But it is rather strange that they are also empty on GET. Could you include your route in your question?

Comment: Done. What do you think? It just doesn't find the keys but when I call them explicitely it does.

Comment: req.params will include values in the URL stem. It will catch "test" if  your route was app.get("/:test",whatever). To read the query string values you could use req.query. I suspect req.param() is smart enough to parse both (req.params and req.query)

Comment: Ok, but it's not what I'm looking for. But I guess there is nothing such as I want in express. And yes, req.param is able to provide query, route and post/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for query parameters:
Object.keys(contexto.req.query);