# How log express.js POST parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I'm wondering how to get an array that contains all parameters sent in a HTTP request.

If I read the doc: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params

I can see that using `req.params` and `req.query`, `params` will be linked to the route parameters and `query` to the GET parameters. But how can I log the post parameters? The `req.param()` method requires an argument and doesn't returns an array if I don't provide one. Since all POST parameters must be used through `req.param()`, there is no way to log them for now. Or am I missing something?

My goal is to efficiently log all parameters to debug easily the application during development, let me know if you have a better way.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, but the title of the other topic doesn't have `express` keyword or in its title so I couldn't find it before, not my fault if it's badly indexed. There is no need to downvote my question which is actually much better indexed. What shold we do? Edit the other topic and add express keyword? That's not a problem to close my topic, I just voted for. I'll edit the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `req.body`, which contains the parsed POST body.  (assuming you have middleware that parses it)

Comment: wouldn't that require express.bodyParser() or similar ?

Comment: @adeneo: Yes; I edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Never saw this option in the doc, they just talk about it once without any link to it. I do have the midleware.

Comment: @SLaks - Yeah, noticed the edit as soon as I posted the comment.

Comment: dupe -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js